# Duration of button being unpressed in arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-nano, proteus

How can I get the duration of how long a button is unpressed? And when the duration excceds 30 seconds I have to perform an event in arduino. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You don't know how to detect the button release or how to calculate the duration?

Comment: All timing questions have something similar to `millis() - starttime` in their core. In your case, you probably update `starttime` whenever the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a code like this who save the last press time and wait until the 30th milliseconds to execute the code. Let me know if it is working, since I haven't tested it.

```
#define BUTTON_PIN 4
unsigned long startTime;
unsigned long lastPress;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);

}
void loop()
{
  
  byte buttonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);
  
  if (buttonState == HIGH) // save the last time button was pressed in milliseconds
  {
      lastPress = millis();
  }
  if ((millis() - lastPress)  > 30000)
  {
  // execute any code you want after 30 seconds

  // reset the counter
  startTime = 0;
  }
}
```